# How can I give persistence to linux environment variables?

Tags: linux, heroku, environment-variables

I'm running a godaddy server and I want to store my sql login credentials in the environment similar to what heroku does.

I followed this:

https://www.godaddy.com/help/how-to-read-and-set-environment-variables-in-centos-12295

```
// write
export TEST=1

// read
echo $TEST
```

but when you set the variables this way the do not persist after you log out and log back in via ssh.

Comment: This is what configuration files -- `~/.bash_profile`, etc -- are for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply put the export statements in your .bashrc file. Your .bashrc file is loaded every time you log in. It's also a good place to put custom aliases and functions you wanna be able to persist too.

Comment: `.bash_profile` -- run only at login -- is better than `.bashrc` -- which is run also for non-login shells, and thus will be also re-exporting your variable in sessions which also inherited it. `.bashrc` is appropriate for aliases and non-exported functions, which are not inherited, as opposed to environment variables and exported functions, which are.

Comment: (Which is to say: `.bashrc` is reloaded much more frequently than merely "every time you log in"; any new interactive non-login shell will reload it).

Comment: Sorry I actually need it as an environment variable which appears to be different.  I'm not able to grab it using this `        $test = getenv("GODADDY_DSN");
` even after I put it in the .bash_profile